# take the drop down to another page

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu

before loading the form for add operator,i must call a web service using the php file addoperator.php which have returned me  a json which contains the values for organisation ,location,building ,i have converted that json values into drop downs,now these drop down must come under the fields organisation,location and building in the form for add operator.

her is the code for  addoperator.php

```
<?php
session_start();
$url='webservice url';
$ch=curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($useridofuser));
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json"));
    $response=  curl_exec($ch);
    echo('\n'."Server response : \n \n".$response);
    curl_close($ch);
    //parsing the json response from server
    $jsonde="$response";
$org = array();
$loc = array();
$bui = array();
$items = json_decode($response);
foreach( $items as $each ){
$loc[]=$each->location[0]->name;
$bui[]=$each->location[0]->building[0];
$org[]=$each->name;
}
?>
<select name="category_id">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
foreach($org as $key=>$val)
{?>
<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $val; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
<select name="category_id">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
foreach($loc as $key=>$val)
{?>
<option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $val; ?></option>
<?php
}
?>
</select>
<select name="category_id">
<option value=""></option>
<?php
foreach($bui as $key=>$val)
{?>
 <option value="<?php echo $key; ?>"><?php echo $val; ?></option>
 <?php
}
?>
</select>
```

the UI of add operator is addoperatorui.php(how can i bring the drop down from addoperator.php to addoperatorui.php)

```
<h3>ADD ROUTER </h3>
    </div>
        <form method="post" action="login.php" >
         <table border="0" >
         <tr><td>Username</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="userid"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Password</td>
                    <td><input name="password" type="password"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Confirm Password</td>
                    <td><input name="password1" type="password"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Email</td>
                    <td><input name="email" type="email"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Organisation Name</td>
                    <td><input name="orgname" type="text"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Location</td>
                    <td><input name="location" type="text"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Building</td>
                    <td><input name="building" type="text"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Department</td>
                    <td><input name="department" type="text"></td></tr>
<?php
$oneYearOn = date('Y-m-d',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", mktime()) . " + 7300 day"));
//echo $oneYearOn;
$oneYearOn1=date('Y-m-d',strtotime(date("Y-m-d", mktime()) . " + 40day"));
//echo $oneYearOn1;
?>
  <tr><td>Sub Category</td>
  <td>
  <select id="Ultra" onchange="run()">  <!--Call run() function-->
 <option value="0">Select</option>
 <option value="<?=$oneYearOn?>">Employee</option>
 <option value="<?=$oneYearOn1?>">Temporary</option>
 </select>  
 </td>
</tr> <tr><td>First Name</td>
                    <td><input name="firstname" type="text"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Last Name</td>
                    <td><input name="lastname" type="text"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Land Phone</td>
                    <td><input name="landphone" type="number"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Mobile</td>
                    <td><input name="mobile" type="number"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Expiry date</td>
                    <?php
                    ?>
 <td><input type="text" id="srt" placeholder="get value on option select"><br></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Opcode</td>
                    <td><input name="opcode" type="text"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Expiry date</td>
                    <td><input name="expirydate" type="date"></td></tr>
                <tr><td>Image</label></td>
                      <td><input type="file" name="image"></td></tr>

                <tr><td><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
```

Comment: What do you mean by bring the drop down from addoperator.php to addoperatorui.php)?

Comment: i would like to take the drop down i have created in operator.php to replace the field organisation in my form

Comment: can i do it with session

Comment: Are you trying to populate <input name="orgname" type="text"> from whatever was selected in <select name="category_id">?

Comment: no i want to take the whole options to the another page any ways i found a solutions by integrating the web service page to the form page